# DNN - Custom Registration Form Field Does Not Validate for Required After Upgrade

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am upgrading a DNN site from version 5.06.00 to version 7.03.02.  I followed the recommended upgrade path, and worked out all of the kinks with the custom modules.  The registration form has a custom boolean field, which is required to be set to TRUE.  This used to validate correctly pre-upgrade, but now it is not post-upgrade.  The user can submit the form without selecting the "TRUE" radio button.

The custom field is displaying properly.  The required asterisk is also displaying.  The DOM even has an error message element with the correct custom required message:

```
<span class='dnnFormMessage dnnFormError'>[required message]</span>
```

However, this field is set to "display:none" by default and never displays as inline like the other error message elements.

I am not a DNN expert and I did not create this site.  I am upgrading it for a client and don't know a ton about how these custom fields all work.  I see the custom field enabled in Admin > Site Settings > User Account Settings > Profile Settings.  I also see a file called "Profile.ascx.Portal-0.resx" that contains the custom field's main text, help text, and required text.  It lives in DesktopModules\Admin\Security\App_LocalResources.  I don't know what else I would need to configure or check that would be different from version 5.6 to 7.3.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've checked all of the requirements, but you didn't mention wheter or not the checkbox to require a valid profile for registration is checked.  Is it?

Can you verify that the custom field is marked as Required?

It may be worth your while to upgrade to the current version of DNN 7, which is 7.04.02.

I'd recommend making a full site backup before doing the upgrade as that is always the right way to proceed.

The .resx file aren't going to affect the functionality, just the texts that are displayed.

I assume that you are doing much of this work on a test copy of the production site.  That being the case, you might want to add another custom boolean field, make it required and see if that one works.

Comment: Thank you.  The field does have the "required" checkbox checked.  Yes, I have a local version of the site where I am making changes.  The site is already upgraded on the Test and Production servers, but the client and I both missed this bug until after the Production deployment.  I have added another test Boolean field like you suggested and it also does not work as expected.  Also, I am not getting any JS errors in the console, and I tried disabling all additional skin JS references on that page.

Comment: Another question I have is: how do I tell DNN that not only is this field required, but you must pick TRUE for it to be valid?  Maybe the required error is not showing because it is set to FALSE by default, so it technically does contain a value?  This didn't seem to be a problem on the older version of DNN, but maybe it's different now?

Comment: There is one more checkbox.  Under Admin, Site Settings, User Account Settings look for the checkbox labelled "Require a valid Profile for Registration" and make sure to check it.

Comment: I have upgraded to 7.04.02 but that made no difference.  The "require a valid profile before registration" box is checked.  A couple of other interesting things about this:  the registration page doesn't work unless you use "?ctl=register' in the URL.  I see some documentaiton about that here, http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/replacing-registration-page-with-custom-and-blocking-the-default-register-page but this must not be what the previous developer did because the name of the page is "Register," which that page says not to do, and on the Site Settings page, "None specified" is selected for

Comment: the "Registration page" setting.  Also, I'm seeing that DNN has some custom radio buttons.  When you click on the buttons, I see that the class name, "dnnRadiobutton-checked," is toggled on the span elements.  However, the input itself does not change.  The default False input stays  as "checked='checked'" no matter what you toggle.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the ideal answer, but since I can't figure out what's wrong DNN-wise, I'm just writing some custom jQuery to find the checked radio button span element, then show/hide that error message based on that.  If there is more than one thing wrong with the form, it will only show this message.  Then if you corrected that boolean, it would show all other messages.  It's not great, but at this point it's better than nothing.

```
$(".dnnPrimaryAction").click(function (e) {
        var $checkedRadioSpan = $(".dnnRadiobutton-checked");
        var $checkedRadioInput = $checkedRadioSpan.prev();
        var $errorMessage = $checkedRadioInput.siblings(".dnnFormError");

        if($checkedRadioInput.val() === "False") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $errorMessage.show();
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage.hide();
            // continue on with other validation
        }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had quite the same problem. It seems that the error message is not displayed for the first form item, as there is not enough place for it.

After adding a header (h2) above the form, it worked fine.

See [Validator errormessage is not displayed](https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/901#3382) in the DNN Community forums for more information.